# how to deploy same job on all my runners?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I have several VMs running `gilab-runner`, and I'm using `gitlab-ci` to deploy microservices into those VMs. Now I want to monitore those VMs with prometheus and grafana, but i need to setup `node-exporter/cadvisor` etc. service into those VMs.

My idea is using gitlab-ci to define a common job for those VMs.

I have already write the `docker-compose.yml` and `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    container_name: node-exporter
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc'
      - '--path.rootfs=/rootfs'
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - '--collector.filesystem.mount-points-exclude=^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc)($$|/)'
    ports:
      - "9100:9100"

  cadvisor:
    image: google/cadvisor
    container_name: cadvisor
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run:/var/run:rw
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
      - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

```yaml
deploy-workers:
  tags:
    - worker
  stage: deploy-workers
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.worker.yaml pull
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.worker.yaml down
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.worker.yaml up -d
```

Then I register the runner in all my VMs with `worker` tag.

However, only one worker job is triggered during ci.

I have about `20` VMs to go.

Do anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

GitLab is probably not the right tool for this. GitLab build pipelines are designed to produce output, not manage state on various servers.  What system did you use to install and configure gitlab-runner on each of these servers? This is the sort of tool you're looking for to manage all of these servers.

Comment: you are right, i'm using docker swarm instead, just run the gitlab-runner on leader node to deploy service.